# Some Form submits from Discussion Module always return generic error message (Updated)

Tags: add-on, error, module, messages

I'm using the EE Discussion module (3.1.8) under EE 2.5.2 and when I submit certain forms, say from the 'Ignore' template for example, the form submits and processes fine, but the returned page shows this error:

```
Error
The following errors were encountered You are not authorized to perform this action
```

The form posts to this URL:

```
http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/forums/do_ignore_member/47211/
```

There is almost NO documentation for the Discussion Forum module so I'm not sure even what controls the form or the message.

The ignore form template code I'm using is:

```
{form_declaration}
<div class="fm-header-wrapper">
    <h3>{lang:ignore_member_confirmation}</h3>
</div>

<div class="fm-message">
    {if member_is_ignored}
        <p class="fm-notice">{lang:already_ignored}</p>
    {/if}

    {if member_not_ignored}
        <p>
            <label for="fm-ignore-member">
                {lang:ignore_member}: <strong>{name}</strong>
            </label>
            <input type='radio' name='action' value='ignore' checked="checked" id="fm-ignore-member" />
        </p>
    {/if}
    {if member_is_ignored}
        <p>
            <label for="fm-unignore-member">
                {lang:unignore_member}: <strong>{name}</strong>
            </label>
            <input type='radio' name='action' value='unignore' checked="checked" id="fm-unignore-member" />
        </p>
    {/if}
    <p class="fm-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="{lang:submit}" />
    </p>
</div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**
I did some more digging on this and it seems that what is adding the duplicate info to the redirected URL is some lines in the /system/expressionengine/modules/forum/mod.forum_core.php code. Specifically in the 'do_ignore_member' function at line 8481

```
$return = str_replace('/'.$this->trigger, '', $this->EE->session->tracker[2]);
```

The $this->EE->session->tracker[2] variable is used on the next line and passed to the redirect call using a $this->forum_path($return); call. The forum_path method checks for the site basepath and then adds the URI value if one is passed in.

```
/**
 * Compiles a path string
 */
public function forum_path($uri = '')
{
    if ($this->basepath == '')
    {
        $this->_forum_set_basepath();
    }

    return $this->EE->functions->remove_double_slashes($this->basepath.$uri.'/');
}
```

**UPDATE #2**
So from my testing I think what is going on here is that the 'needle' value on the str_replace() is incorrect. EE adds a beginning slash '/' to the trigger word and then searches the `$this->EE->session->tracker[2]` value for that value and removes it. The trouble is, at least from what I can see, is that the `$this->EE->session->tracker[2]` value does NOT have a leading '/' so no match is found. I think the fix would be to change the line 8481 in the /system/expressionengine/modules/forum/mod.forum_core.php file from:

```
$return = str_replace('/'.$this->trigger, '', $this->EE->session->tracker[2]);
```

to:

```
$return = str_replace($this->trigger, '', $this->EE->session->tracker[2]);
```

This seems to fix the trouble for me, but I ask. Is this a truly a bug that needs this fix or am I just missing another configuration setting someplace?

Comment: OK. I found the problem, but I still don't know what is causing it. Looks like on the redirect EE is appending an extra '/forums' to the landing URL. So after using the 'ignore' link in a thread (say thread ID 123) and submitting the form EE is attempting to redirect back to the thread at the URL:  

`http://dev.macobserver.com/tmo/forums/forums/viewthread/123`  

The appropriate URL would be:  

`http://dev.macobserver.com/tmo/forums/viewthread/123`  

Which doesn't return the error.

I checked mu setting and for 'FORUM URL' I have '/tmo/forums/' and for Forum Triggering Word it's 'forums'

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say there's a good chance that this is down to a bug in the forum module. Are you able to post a link to a public page that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing 'forums/' from the "forum url" setting...

So '/tmo/forums/' becomes '/tmo/'. You might have to remove the trailing slash as well.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that and the odd thing is that it doesn't seem to make a difference what value I put in there. The URL still redirects the same.

Comment: Figured this one out. For that path to be used you need to be sure to set the `$env_config['use_forum_url'] = 'y';` hidden config variable. Unfortunately still doesn't 100% resolve my issue because when I enable that then my form POST urls are missing the /forums bit since it's not set. If I add /forums to the "forum url" setting I again get duplicate /forums because the `$this->EE->session->tracker[2]` value also contains the /forums bit. This is feeling more like an EE bug

Comment: Try a different forum trigger word just for kicks... Also, are you using the most recent version of the Forum module?

Comment: Yeah, changing the keyword just breaks the forum which would be expected. I'm on version 3.1.8 of the forum module. latest is 3.1.9, so I may try updating. Although in looking at the lines in question in the mod.forum_core.php they seem to be the same in both versions, so if it is indeed a bug then I don't think it's fixed.